# kafka consumer reads the same message

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a single Topic with 5 partitions.
I have 5 threads, each creating a Consumer 
All consumer are with the same consumer group using group.id.
I also gave each consumer a different and unique client.id

I see that 2 consumers are reading the same message to process
Should kafka handle this?
How do I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1):

Consumers within the same group should not receive the same messages. The partitions should be split across all consumers and at any time Kafka's consumer group logic ensures only 1 consumer is assigned to each partition.

The exception is if 1 consumer crashes before it's able to commit its offset. In that case, the new consumer that gets assigned the partition will re-consume from the last committed offset.

You can use the consumer group tool `kafka-consumer-groups` that comes with Kafka to check the partitions assigned to each consumer in your group.

Comment: Thanks. I have auto commit set to true with 1000 as ms for commit time.

Comment: I have auto commiy set to true. What can cause it to fail?

Comment: Are you sure the same message was not sent to multiple partitions ?
Also use the consumer group tool to confirm you see all your consumers and see which partitions they are assigned to.

Comment: Yes Iam using kafka viewer to see there is a single message. Also there is a single consumer group wuth 5 consumers.